# Unknown discriminator value MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

I want a collection that saves multiple types of objects/documents but all of them inherit from a base interface.. However, I am getting this exception when loading:

`Additional information: An error occurred while deserializing the Inventory property of class Character: Unknown discriminator value 'TestItem'.`

Here is my codes:

```
public class Character
{
    ...
    public List<IInventoryItem> Inventory { get; set; }
    ...
}

public interface IInventoryItem
{
...
}

class TestItem : IInventoryItem
{
...
}
```

Help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The problem is that you don't explicitly declare your polymorphic types to MongoDB driver.

For that, you have two options: using attributes, or a mapping configuration method. More info here: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/reference/bson/mapping/

Using attributes:

```cs
[BsonDiscriminator("TestItem")]
public class TestItem : IInventoryItem
{
    ...
}
```

Using mapping configuration method:

```cs
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<TestItem>(); // do it before you access DB
```

WHY: documents that represent polymorphic types (e.g. interfaces) are saved to the DB with a special field named `_t`, which contains discriminator value. In your case, the `Character` document will look like this:

```js
{
    // ... other fields
    Inventory: [
        {
            _t: "TestItem",
            //... other fields
        }, 
        {
            _t: "TestItem",
            //... other fields
        }
    ]
    // ... other fields
}
```

On write, if the mappings don't exist, they are created on the fly, and `TestItem` discriminator is mapped to `TestItem` class. From that moment on, the mappings exist for the life of the `AppDomain`. Thus for example, if you perform reads after writes, it will be OK.

But if you read data first thing, BSON serializer doesn't know what type the `TestItem` discriminator maps to. So it is good practice to always explicitly specify discriminator mappings. In this way you can also control discriminator values - by default they equal to type name.

Comment: Thanks for help a lot but I am still getting the same error for some reason.

Comment: Actually the second method worked.. any reason why the attribute didn't.. I'd prefer to use that.

Comment: What version of MongoDB C# driver do you use?

Comment: Sorry, forgot about you :P
2.4.0 currently.

Comment: Good explanation! Thanks.

Comment: @felix-b Hi. I was trying to see your assumption , but when I first tried to read from mongo  , I was expecting to see this error , but I didnt ( and I did restarted the AppDomain each time). can you please tell me why am I not seeing this error ? https://i.imgur.com/imam0La.jpg . BTW It's the mapping , so even if I remove it , I see error but another one : https://i.imgur.com/kQvKjnc.jpg . I don't understand what's going on here  - How can I change my code to see this error of the OP ? ( mongo driver 2.11.0)

Comment: Can u plz look at my last comment ?

Comment: you are a life saver :)